# Connect Mongo Error: 'express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am just trying implement authentication and sessions into my app by following a tutorial. I am currently stuck on problems probably due to updated packages. I am using `express-session` and `connect-mongo` but i keep getting the error "provide secret..."

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require('axios');
const User = require('./models/user')
const app = express()

mongoose.connect(process.env.ATLAS_URI).then(console.log("MongoDB Connection Success")).catch(err => console.log("MongoDB Connection Failed" + err))
// For backend and express init
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))


app.use(session({
  sercret: 'random secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.ATLAS_URI }),
}));
```

For more context, the guide i was following was https://medium.com/swlh/set-up-an-express-js-app-with-passport-js-and-mongodb-for-password-authentication-6ea05d95335c

Comment: Typo in your setup: `sercret`

Comment: i feel stupid, thank you!!!.

Answer (score 0):

**To migrate the library from V3 to V4, re-install the dependencies.**

**If you are using npm**

1. npm uninstall connect-mongo
2. npm uninstall @types/connect-mongo
3. npm install connect-mongo

**If you are using yarn**

1. yarn remove connect-mongo
2. yarn remove @types/connect-mongo
3. yarn add connect-mongo

**Next step is to import the dependencies**

**Javascript:**

const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');

**Typescript**:

import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';

**Create the store using MongoStore.create(options) instead of new MongoStore(options)**

app.use(session({
secret: 'foo',
store: MongoStore.create(options)
}));